# Building a dictionary based on ranks

Tags: python, dictionary, poker

I'm creating a simplified program of Texas hold'em and I'm trying to create a function that builds a dictionary based upon the ranks of the cards.

For example, if I have:

```
H1: [6c, 2c, 6d, 6h, 2h, 6s, 3s]
H2: [6c, 2c, 6d, 6h, 2h, 3s, Ad]
```

I want to get something that looks like:
`{2: [2c, 2h], 3: [3s], 6: [6c, 6d, 6h, 6s]}` when I call my function for `H1`.
So I want to take the 7 cards and build a dictionary based upon the ranks. In this instance, I'm looking for four of a kind.

Comment: I'd really recommend using a dedicated library for hand scoring, dealing out cards, etc. In python I suggest [https://github.com/worldveil/deuces](https://github.com/worldveil/deuces).

Answer (score 3):

```
In [51]: import operator

In [52]: import itertools as IT

In [53]: H1 =  ['6c', '2c', '6d', '6h', '2h', '6s', '3s']

In [54]: {rank:list(group) for rank, group in IT.groupby(sorted(H1), key=operator.itemgetter(slice(None, -1)))}
Out[54]: {'2': ['2c', '2h'], '3': ['3s'], '6': ['6c', '6d', '6h', '6s']}
```

or

```
In [65]: {rank:list(group) for rank, group in IT.groupby(sorted(H1), key=lambda card: card[:-1])}
Out[65]: {'2': ['2c', '2h'], '3': ['3s'], '6': ['6c', '6d', '6h', '6s']}
```

Note that if the ten of clubs is represented by `'10c'` then to peel off the rank you would need `operator.itemgetter(slice(None, -1))`. On the other hand, if you represented the ten of clubs with `'tc'`, then `operator.itemgetter(0)` would suffice.